# How can i make my buttons apear inline, next to text?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have just started using bootstrap. I am wanting to create a web app with this [design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/voW3g.png)

As you can see there is a celsius and fahrenheit button displayed right next to the tempriture.

I have had no joy with my attempt:

```
<div>
    <h1 id="temperature" class="text-center inline">temperature</h1>
        <div class="btn-group inline pull-right" data-toggle="buttons-checkbox">
          <div class="btn btn-primary unitButton">C</div>
          <div class="btn btn-primary unitButton">F</div>
        </div>
</div>
```

Can someone please help me. Thank you for your time.

Comment: why not use _span.btn_ instead of the div? Or render the _div.btn_ as _display=inline_?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add `display:inline-block;` to h1

```
#temperature{

display:inline-block;

}
```

and take off the class `pull-right` from the div parent of the buttons:

```
<div>
    <h1 id="temperature" class="text-center inline">temperature</h1>
        <div class="btn-group inline" data-toggle="buttons-checkbox">
          <div class="btn btn-primary unitButton">C</div>
          <div class="btn btn-primary unitButton">F</div>
        </div>
</div>
```

[**Demo**](http://www.bootply.com/ZFGWHvGWF0)